# Stop YouTube playback on click

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'm building a video module using this as a basic navigation framework:

https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/17/horizontal-slide-out-menu/

I have 5 tabs, and in each submenu, a single list item that contains a different YouTube playlist (vid_frame1 - vid_frame5).

In each of the 5 instances of the ul.cbp-hssubmenu li a is clicked (each of the 5 have a color-named class: orange, blue1, red, blue2, green) any of the videos playing in any of the vid_frames would stop playing. I've tried doing an onClick right on the ul.cbp-hssubmenu li a, but that seems to break the content from displaying. I would think some kind of eventListener would do the trick, but my JS knowledge is limited. TIA for any assistance!

Comment: Have you tried any code? Can you share it?

Comment: Here is a codepen link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NjByRo Its not loading the videos for some reason in this environment, but it is locally for me. Does this help?

Comment: Check the [player.stopVideo()](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) in the Youtube IFRAME API.

Stops and cancels loading of the current video. This function should be reserved for rare situations when you know that the user will not be watching additional video in the player

snippet:

var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }

Comment: @noogui - thanks for the tip! How would I go about assigning this to the various top level tabs? (tab1, tab2, etc) Would this be a added between script tags within the page?